# Prettier without white space before / in HTML closed tag?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

For Example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
<br /><br />
<input type="reset" />
```

How do I use the "Prettier" extension in vscode without white space before `/>` in closed tag?